# Plot two list for differen first list parameter

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, simulation

I have a series of equations based on which I plot final lists of "xA1","yB1".

I need to change "xA1 = {0.55}" and "yB1 = {0.6}" between [0,1] with interval 0.01 (in part:   ***    List1: XA & XB    ***  of my code) and plot final lists of "xA1","yB1" in one shape.
any idea?

```
a = 150; b = -150; c = -200; d = -500; e = 0; f = -300; g = 0; h = -100; dt = 0.001;
```

```
(***    List1: XA & XB    ***)
    xA1 = {0.55};
    xA2 = {1 - xA1[[1]]};
    yB1 = {0.6};
    yB2 = {1 - yB1[[1]]};
```

```
(***    List2: fitness of A     ***)
UA1 = {(yB1[[1]]*b + yB2[[1]]*f)*dt}
UA2 = {(yB1[[1]]*d + yB2[[1]]*h)*dt}
```

```
(***    List3: average fitness A    ***)
UA = {(xA1[[1]]*(yB1[[1]]*b + yB2[[1]]*f) + xA2[[1]]*(yB1[[1]]*d + yB2[[1]]*h))*dt}
```

```
(***    List4: fitness of B     ***)
UB1 = {(xA1[[1]]*a + xA2[[1]]*c)*dt}
UB2 = {(xA1[[1]]*e + xA2[[1]]*g)*dt}
```

```
(***    List5: average fitness B   ***)
UB = {(yB1[[1]]*(xA1[[1]]*a + xA2[[1]]*c) + 
     yB2[[1]]*(xA1[[1]]*e + xA2[[1]]*g))*dt}
```

```
(***    Main Function   ***)
For[t = 1, t < 100, t++,
 
 (***    fitnesses A    ***)
 uA1 = yB1[[t]]*b + yB2[[t]]*f;
 uA2 = yB1[[t]]*d + yB2[[t]]*h;
 uA = xA1[[t]]*uA1 + xA2[[t]]*uA2;
 UA1 = Append[UA1, uA1*dt];
 UA2 = Append[UA2, uA2*dt];
 UA = Append[UA, uA*dt];
 
 (***    fitnesses B    ***)
 uB1 = xA1[[t]]*a + xA2[[t]]*c;
 uB2 = xA1[[t]]*e + xA2[[t]]*g;
 uB = yB1[[t]]*uB1 + yB2[[t]]*uB2;
 UB1 = Append[UB1, uB1*dt];
 UB2 = Append[UB2, uB2*dt];
 UB = Append[UB, uB*dt];
 
 (***    differential equations A    ***)
 xA1 = Append[xA1, xA1[[t]] + (xA1[[t]]*(uA1 - uA))*dt];
 xA2 = Append[xA2, xA2[[t]] + (xA2[[t]]*(uA2 - uA))*dt];
 
 (***    differential equations B    ***)
 yB1 = Append[yB1, yB1[[t]] + (yB1[[t]]*(uB1 - uB))*dt];
 yB2 = Append[yB2, yB2[[t]] + (yB2[[t]]*(uB2 - uB))*dt];
 ]
```

````
ListLinePlot[{Labeled[xA1, "share of strategy A1 Palyer A"], 
  Labeled[yB1, "share of strategy B1 Palyer B"]}, ImageSize -> Large, 
 PlotTheme -> "Detailed", PlotRange -> 1 , PlotRangeClipping -> False]
```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion would be, to sum up, your code in a function depending on the variables "xA1" and "yB1".

```
fun[XA1_, YB1_] := Block[{xA1, yB1, plot},
(***List1:XA& XB***)
xA1 = {XA1};
xA2 = {1 - xA1[[1]]};
yB1 = {YB1};
yB2 = {1 - yB1[[1]]};

(***List2:fitness of A***)
UA1 = {(yB1[[1]]*b + yB2[[1]]*f)*dt};
UA2 = {(yB1[[1]]*d + yB2[[1]]*h)*dt};
  
(***List3:average fitness A***)
UA = {(xA1[[1]]*(yB1[[1]]*b + yB2[[1]]*f) + 
   xA2[[1]]*(yB1[[1]]*d + yB2[[1]]*h))*dt};

(***List4:fitness of B***)
UB1 = {(xA1[[1]]*a + xA2[[1]]*c)*dt};
UB2 = {(xA1[[1]]*e + xA2[[1]]*g)*dt};

(***List5:average fitness B***)
UB = {(yB1[[1]]*(xA1[[1]]*a + xA2[[1]]*c) + 
   yB2[[1]]*(xA1[[1]]*e + xA2[[1]]*g))*dt};

(***Main Function***)
For[t = 1, t < 100, t++,(***fitnesses A***)
 uA1 = yB1[[t]]*b + yB2[[t]]*f;
 uA2 = yB1[[t]]*d + yB2[[t]]*h;
 uA = xA1[[t]]*uA1 + xA2[[t]]*uA2;
 UA1 = Append[UA1, uA1*dt];
 UA2 = Append[UA2, uA2*dt];
 UA = Append[UA, uA*dt];
 (***fitnesses B***)uB1 = xA1[[t]]*a + xA2[[t]]*c;
 uB2 = xA1[[t]]*e + xA2[[t]]*g;
 uB = yB1[[t]]*uB1 + yB2[[t]]*uB2;
 UB1 = Append[UB1, uB1*dt];
 UB2 = Append[UB2, uB2*dt];
 UB = Append[UB, uB*dt];
 (***differential equations A***)
 xA1 = Append[xA1, xA1[[t]] + (xA1[[t]]*(uA1 - uA))*dt];
 xA2 = Append[xA2, xA2[[t]] + (xA2[[t]]*(uA2 - uA))*dt];
 (***differential equations B***)
   yB1 = Append[yB1, yB1[[t]] + (yB1[[t]]*(uB1 - uB))*dt];
 yB2 = Append[yB2, yB2[[t]] + (yB2[[t]]*(uB2 - uB))*dt];
 ];

plot = ListLinePlot[{Labeled[xA1, "share of strategy A1 Palyer A"], Labeled[yB1, "share of strategy B1 Palyer B"]}, 
ImageSize -> Large, PlotTheme -> "Detailed", PlotRange -> 1, 
PlotRangeClipping -> False];

Return[plot];
]
```

You can then call that function with the desired parameters, e.g. fun[0.55, 0.6]. With a pair of tables you can scan your parameter space:

```
Table[Table[fun[xA1,yB1],{xA1,0,1,0.01}],{yB1,0,1,0.01}]
```

Comment: Thanks for your idea. Actually I wanted to do the same as your solution but I did not know how to do that. Can you help me?

Comment: I edited my answer to include the entire function. I copied all of your code into one function. You may want to learn more about functions in Mathematica; see https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FunctionsAndPrograms.html#13037 or  https://www.wolfram.com/wolfram-u/all-classes-courses/ .

Comment: Thank you very much Flow, I test it, it work for Fun[0.55,0.6] and etc, but for Table[Table[fun[xA1,yB1],{xA1,0,1,0.01}],{yB1,0,1,0.01}] the output was too many plot shapes, , while I want all of them ({xA1,0,1,0.01}],{yB1,0,1,0.01}) to be displayed in one shape.
how I can do that?

Comment: You could use Show[] (https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Show.html) with the option PlotRange->All to overlay the plots.